# What is Profile Diagram in Software Architecture?

Tags: architecture, uml

May I know the importance of Profile diagram in Software Architecture.
What are the problem I would face, If I skip this diagram in Software development?

Comment: Your question is too vague, you need to edit it and give us more details. Please read [mcve] in order to properly edit your question

Comment: Making a poll (how popular) is off-topic at SO, too.

Comment: Hello @ThomasKilian, now I have removed how popular it is. Do you have any more modification need with this question to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profile gathers business objects for a certain domain that will be used in many models to be created in that domain. The profile uses stereotypes to group those central objects. Attributes giving a formal description of them are used when later applying the profile elements. That is, when you create a (real) model and apply a stereotype from your profile, the element will have tagged values created from the attributes. These can be used to describe meta-information and/or to control the model in various ways (behavior/code generation, etc.).

Whenever you have to create large and/or multiple models it is a good idea to survey the business domain first and create a meta-model in form of a profile. Enterprise Architect calls this technique MDG and it is very popular amongst the users (what I can read from their forum).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, @Thomas Kilian. May yo do a favor for me you suggest any best e-book to learn about these diagrams

Comment: Well, I wrote a book about the use of so-called MDGs in Enterprise Architect. They are on top of profiles. I think I included a significant part to describe profiles and why one should use them. It's the last on this page: http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html You can download a sample. Maybe that already contains the important part for you.